# How to divide product price value with a fixed number in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to divide product price £56 with 3 print at the bottom of the page using JavaScript. I have googled it for more than 8 hours & tried with out currency symbol too. but no luck.

**Java Script**

```
<script>
    
var a = document.getElementById('#price1');
var b = 3;
var result = (a / b);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div id="price1">£51</div>
<div id="result"></div>

</body>
```

Updated few errors but the result is 0 now.

Comment: There are a couple of things here - first, price1 isn't a classname, it's an ID in your html code, so you need to use `document.getElementById`, not `getElementsByClassName`. Second, instead of `document.write`, try giving your result div an id of `result`, and then `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result`

Comment: updated the errors but the result "0"

Comment: drop the # : var a = document.getElementById('price1');

Comment: ok, that sounds like it might be happening because of the Euro sign. If you want to keep that, you'll need to remove that from the string and use parseInt, i.e. `var result = parseInt(a.substr(1))/b`

Comment: Tried without # and removed £ from price. now getting NaN.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is slightly different from the existing ones. I used `textContent` to grab the text inside the #price element, and remember to remove the `#` inside `getElementById`, since you don't need it to specify that it's an id. Then be sure to use `parseInt()` to convert the 51 into a number, since all text content inside elements are strings. Then I just used `const` instead of `var`, since that's a slightly more modern way to write Javascript.

```js
const a = parseInt(document.getElementById('price1').textContent)
const b = 3
const result = a / b

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div id="price1">51</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Edit: if the text content might have a pound sign prepended to it:

```js
let a = document.getElementById('price1').textContent
a = parseInt(a.match(/\d+/)[0])
const b = 3
const result = a / b

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div id="price1">£51</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Great! It works when the price doesn't have £

Comment: how to limit the output decimal 2?

Comment: i have limited the decimal by result.toFixed(2)

Answer (score 1):

this will be more complicated.but more general.
You can use it in any currency.

```js
const a_str = document.getElementById('price1').textContent

const re = /\d+/
const a = a_str.match(re)  // get number from text use regex

const placeholder = "{1}" // or anything unusual
const outer_text = a_str.replace(re,placeholder) //replace number by placeholder

const b = 3
const c = a / b
const result = outer_text.replace(placeholder,c) //replace placeholder by result

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result
```

```html
<div id="price1">£51</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your js:
document.querySelectorAll('.result")[0].innerHTML=result;

Comment: I think instead of `document.querySelectorAll` we should use `document.querySelector`

Answer (score 0):

```
const priceDiv = document.querySelector("#price1")
const resultDiv = document.querySelector("#result")

const price = priceDiv.innerHTML.slice(1)
const result = price / 3

resultDiv.innerHTML = `£${result}`
```

Comment: `String.slice()` returns everything after the first character in the price div, so it returns '1'

Comment: Based on example `£51` will return `51`

Comment: You're right, sorry. He keeps editing it back and forth.